# IoT hub event ingestion and data storage

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm using an Azure stream Analytics job to process the data from an IoT hub.  So my data comes from my simulated device to an IoT hub and I have configured the hub as an input to the stream analytics job and a blob storage as an output job.

My question is if I stop the stream analytics job and restart it, do I lose the data between stop and start?  Or is the data stored on the IoT hub and when I restart the job and select the start time as from when it stopped, I'll get all the data.

Comment: Hello, have you checked the issue? And is there any other question?

Answer (score 1):

As krishmam said, you can choose the outputStartMode when starting a job. Specifies if the job should start producing output at a given timestamp or at the point when the job starts. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose any data. Stream Analytics gives you an option to start a job from the previous stop time when you start the job.